# Example of a non noetherian module $M$ s.t. $M/IM$ is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, artinian

1. What is an example of a non noetherian module $M$ s.t. $M/IM$ is noetherian?
2. What is an example of a non artinian module $M$ s.t. $M/IM$ is artinian?

What I was thinking that $k[x_1,...,x_n,...]$ is not noetherian but $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is noetherian and the later is contained in the previous one, so I am done. What about the artinian case?

Comment: What about $k[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: This will be a field $k$. Which is arttinian. Isn't it?

Comment: The module $k[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1,...,x_n)k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a vector space over the field $k$, and therefore Artinian. However $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is not

Comment: Yes the quotient will be $k$ right? Which is artinian but $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ wouldn't be.

Comment: Is $I$ here intended to be a submodule of $M$, or an ideal in your ring? If $I$ is a submodule then yes the resulting quotient is the field $k$. Otherwise it would be a finite dimensional vector space with basis $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Either way the quotient is Artinian

Comment: And if $I$ is nilpotent then how to prove $R$ is noetherian as well as Artinian.

Comment: May I know why am I downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R$ to be your favorite non-noetherian (hence non-artinian) commutative ring, $M=R$ and $I$ a maximal ideal of $R$.